# Principled Volume Shader shows edges of its Domain/Object

Tags: materials, volumetrics

When I use a material comprised of a Principled Volume shader on an object used as the volume domain, I see the outline of the object/domain.  Is there a way to "pad" the edges of the domain or something to add to the material or a setting adjustment so that the volume inside has a more natural/cloudy/smokey look?  Attached is an example of the problem.
[image]

Comment: Probably add a screen of your cloud object in wire mode to better understand what shape is made of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not answering your Q, but you could be interested to try another approach with **Object type Volume**.

Model a base shape (from cubes or in *Sculpt* mode from sphere) here Cubes with Subdivision modifier) ...

[image]

Add object (Shift+A) *Volume > Empty* and add **Mesh to Volume** modifier and set your base mesh as source object ...

[image]

Then add **Volume Displace** modifier (like *Strength* 2), add a new texture and under texture properties choose *Cloud* texture with some bigger Size ...

[image]

Alternatively you can combine with other Volume Displace using another cloud texture with smaller size for more details ...

[image]

In this example I don't even need a shader (material) all is set in modifier or texture properties.

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is so out-of-the-box from my approach - thank you!  I will certainly give this a go!

Comment: Fantastic!  This is a game-changer.  My many thanks for your taking the time to post this approach.  I hope it will help others, too.  Cheers!

Comment: Done! Thanks very much again :)