# Volumetric objects with smooth transitions towards the outside but noise texture defining transparent and opaque parts

Tags: node-editor

I am pretty much a beginner in Blender and know some basics of the software, but have knowledge of other 3d software like LightWave and Vue Infinite.

I would like to have some smooth volumetric objects as a starting point for different kind of uses and would render with Cycles (volumetric lights, nebulas, auroras etc.). The reason that I would like to use a volumetric with smooth borders is to avoid those harsh borders where an applied noise meets the extremes of the mesh/primitive that limits the volumetric.

I found this interesting discussion with examples and was able to replicate the node setup of one of the suggested methods.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/.../how-to-make...

Now I am confronted with the question/challenge how and where I should plug in a noise texture into the node setup, which should define the transparent and opaque parts of the volume.

First screenshot shows the node setup for a volumetric with smooth borders, the second screenshot an example of a noise texture (from the Procedural Noise Pack Pro) that I would like to incorporate into the node setup without harsh transitions towards the limits of the volumetric.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Could be related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287393/2214   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/201083/2214  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287393/2214. Those links doesn't mix textures as you requested but they are using Volume Displace modifier .... If that is not what you are looking for ....just notify it in your question :) Thanks

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of volume displacing and will have to make a few tests in order to see if it does what I was expecting. Keep you informed and thank you a lot for directing me to this alternative. With regards, Ralf Maeder.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **Subtract** (*Math* node) seems to be working ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Awesome and simple at least for those shapes that can be covered by the gradient texture node, like primitives. I'll do some testing with this setup to see how flexible it is or can be expanded for custom meshes. With regards, Ralf Maeder.

Comment: Just connecting your node-tree (last Multiplanode) into upper socket of Subtract node (instead of my Gradient node) should work for you.

Comment: If this answer solved your issue consider mark it as accepted, so others can see this answer as solved from main list. https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Thank you keep this site organised.

Comment: I made a small change to your proposed setup and changed the "subtract node" to "smooth minimum". This allows me to adjust an inset of the volumetric filling. Thank you so much. I would add a screenshot, but apparently comments only allow text!?

Comment: Great you are satisfied :) Yes, comments are text based. You can paste only a link to an image hosted somewhere, like imagur.com is often used here for tmp sharing.