# How to make cumulonimbus clouds?

Tags: shaders, volumetrics

I would like to make one as a volumetric object, but I have no idea how. Any suggestions? Best would be to use VDBs that are already done, but I haven't found a single one online, paid or free.

Below are some examples of cumulonimbus clouds. These are very distinctive for their sort of mushroom-like shape that kind of stretches out into this saucer type thing. The bottom also flares out a bit, but not as much. The "saucer" section seems a lot smoother, while the bottom and the very top has details similar to the more "fluffy" cumulus clouds.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Related (or duplicated?) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287393/2214

Comment: Not really unfortunately :/

Comment: Hi, Geri .. to the naïve reader, (me :) ) @vklidu 's  link looks very similar.. perhaps you could edit your question to with a link to explain what extra details you're looking for, here. That would help us to answer you more accurately.

Comment: I added some more info. Cumulonimbus clouds are more "specialized" so to speak, I'm looking for more than simple blobs of clouds. The shape here is paramount.

Comment: @Geri ... Is there anything that block you to reuse technique from the link? Like generate it from two meshes - top and bottom "fluffy" part and second for a "neck" part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @vklidu, I could make these clouds pretty easily, using the method in this [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/287393/85951).

Starting from an *UV Sphere*, model the basic shape of the cloud using proportional editing.

[image]

Then *Add* -> *Volume* -> *Empty* and add a *Mesh to Volume* modifier to it. Make sure the *Exterior Band Width* is set to a low number, so the top rim of the cloud stays as thin as possible.

[image]

Then you can add 2 *Volume Displace* modifiers. These will be for adding larger, and smaller noise to the cloud. You can use these settings. Make sure you select the correct modifier when changing the noise scales of the textures, and that you have 2 textures, and not changing the 1 texture back and forth.

[image]

After adding a simple *Principled Volume* shader (or [this fancy shader](https://youtu.be/dyAXWSwCqKg)), you're pretty much done with the main cloud, but you can further decorate it with pre-made VBD clouds, by scattering them at the base. You can simply place these by hand, so you can easily change their positions and rotations.

[image]

Finally, you can add a *Cube* with a low density volume shader to add some atmosphere.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### VDB to Mesh + Sculpt ...

Import some existing VDB cloud ...

[image]

You can't convert *Volume* object into a mesh directly, but I just noticed - you can add some mesh object (like a Plane) and use *Volume* object in *Geometry Nodes* and do conversion with **Volume to Mesh** node ...

[image]
[image]

Now you can *Apply* modifier and sculpt mesh into desired shape ...

[image]

... than use *Mesh to Volume* technique above (modifier or Geometry Nodes > Mesh to Volume) ... or like here I just assigned Volumetric Principled shader to mesh.

[image]

Tip: nice [Cloud Shader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyAXWSwCqKg)

Comment: Wow we have a weatherman, so many different techniques for making clouds. Nice results

Comment: .. and before the volumetrics, a mighty fine crop of broccoli ! (Don't worry, I'll see myself out..)

Comment: Weatherman ... ha :) yeah, right I love clouds ... why I didn't try them before ... ah now I know time consuming :) @Robin ... I had exact the same feeling :) Why I put so much effort to this ... message for OP - just download a broccoli and assign volumetric :)

Comment: Hah! Thanks a lot :D This is medhod will be perfect.

Comment: Great if it works for you ... it is just quite calculation intensive - a lot of topology ... it is good to use remesh in some cases ... and of course volumetric shader is not the same as "density" texture that is not even ... BTW nice shader for clouds https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyAXWSwCqKg

Comment: Yeah I'm defintely going to use remesh. I found that tutorial just yesterday, pretty amazing.